# For how long will Exoplayer play in the background?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have used Exoplayer to play an audio stream. You can see the code below. I am not a professional Android dev, but I know that on android if you want something to run in the background you have to use services. I did not expect this player to play in the background, but it does. My question is. Is this enough will the player work fine in the background, does exoplayer handle bacground mode by default, or will the player be shut down after a while. So is it still necessary to make a service that runs in the background?

```
private fun setUpPlayer(){
            val renderersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(this)
            val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, renderersFactory, trackSelector)
            val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "FOOBAR")
            val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(radioLink), DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent), DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null)
            exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ***will*** need a service to run exoplayer, i have had experience with this when i was trying out exoplayer. First of all android will destroy your activity along with the instance of your exoplayer.

On back press or in background the app will still be able to play but eventually after couple of minutes it will stop as android tries to free resources.

It is actually very good to do things via service so you can do much without doing heavy task on your activity main thread.

You just need a foreground service which also requires a notification with a specific channel, you can also make the notification of media style so you can control your playback through notification or even when the screen is locked.

[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpD5RZtbCc) tutorial explains how to work with service

Why you need service (Quote from this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services))?

> You should only use a foreground service when your app needs to
> perform a task that is noticeable by the user even when they're not
> directly interacting with the app.

As per one of your comments it seem that while development the exoplayer is luckily alive but i would say once you deploy your app to different devices you may want to rethink on the approach of using activity or service for exoplayer.

Comment: i watched the video. I did not understand why I need this App class he created. Everything works without it.

Comment: @DinuNicolae then i must insist you provide OS version and device details plus the time of playback you are getting without using service, i am amused that the player still plays mean while i happen to find the android system kills activity and exoplayer instance. If you did not get much help from the video then i suggest you check the answer by oziomajnr where he has posted a very good article on services and activity, check the statement right above the hierarchy pyramid in the article.

Comment: I did get help from the video. And everything works fine. I get a service and even if I close the app I have that notification that I can press and open the app again. My question was why I need that "App" class he created, cause it works just as well without it. If you remember he created a service, but also an app class.

Comment: @DinuNicolae no you wont need to create that class extending application, you can create the notification channel in your service.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a service because you cannot ensure the music would continue playing in the background. The android operating system would kill your application if it needs resources to run other apps that are in the foreground or that are using services, you can check out this article for more information [Who lives and who dies? Process priorities on Android](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f).
If you keep the music playing long enough, then it would stop playing after the app is killed.